# spring boot micro services application - Is it mandatory to have main method

Tags: spring-boot, microservices

```
I am new to spring boot micro services. I googled it . All of the examples used the below method
```

```
<pre>
public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(sample.class, args);
    }
</pre>
```

Is it mandatory to have above method for commercial projects also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any Java program that is runnable or an application must have a `main` method.

> In the Java programming language, every application must contain a main method whose signature is:
>
> ```java
>    public static void main(String[] args)
> ```

This is documented in this [Hello World](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/index.html#MAIN) tutorial. A Spring Boot application is just a Java application at its core with many features to make it easier for people to make microservices, other types of web applications and libraries.

A library or shared code usually packaged as a jar file that does a partial task in an application doesn't have to have a `main`, but it might. Sometimes libraries do have a `main` for testing or examples. It is possible for each class to have a single `main` of its own. However, an application can only start from one of them. A `main` method in another class could be called in a running program just like any other method, but only one `main` is called to start the application.

The `main` method used to start an application is often referred to as an [entry point](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html). If a class is defined as the `Main-Class` in a jar file's manifest, then the `main` method in that class will be used as the entry point for the application. It is called by the system [JRE](https://jdk.java.net/) usually by double clicking on the jar or thru a cli command such as `java -jar jarfilename.jar`.

Therefore, if you want to package your code into a library that an application uses, you don't need a `main`. If you are creating a standalone Spring Boot application you are required to have a `main`. The Spring Boot framework will be able to use that `main` to make a runnable jar file.